# Migrating a SQL Azure database from SQL Server 2008 to 2014 in the cloud

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, azure

I need to clarify the following information

"The database copy operation copies a Microsoft Azure SQL Database to a new database. The copy can be created on the same or a different logical server. When the copying process completes, the new database is a fully functioning database that is independent of the source database."

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff951624.aspx.

Does this mean that, for example, I have a SQL Azure database which runs on SQL Server 2008 and I can copy this database to other server, where it will run on SQL Server 2014?

In general, I'm looking for a way to migrate an Azure SQL DB from 2008 to 2014 SQL server using REST API, and I can't find anything better than that.

UPDATE: I'm confused about what version of SQL server is SQL Azure.

Comment: what do you mean by Azure SQL DB 2008 ?! There is no azure SQL DB 2008! Azure SQL Database is a SQL Service, not a server. If you mean SQL Server on Azure VM, then there is no REST API to help you with that! Please clarify your question, as it is confusing!

Comment: "Azure SQL Database is a SQL Service, not a server." - Yes. So Azure SQL does't care what DB (created in 2008 or 2014 SQL server) are you uploading when migrating it from on-premise to SQL Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The copy operation you are referring to works only across Microsoft Azure SQL Database and not with on-prem versions of SQL Server. From the perspective of Microsoft Azure SQL the versioning of the on-prem SQL Server product does not matter.

Additionally, the copy operations does not copy the data from one database to another. It creates a fully transactionally consistent copy of a stand-alone database and provides you a fresh new copy of the full database. That means, even if there was a versioning issue the target database created would be the same version of the original database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I will vote your answer up when l get enough reputation.

Comment: Default compatibility level on Azure SQL DB (today) is 100 (SQL 2008). The database engine version is a custom one for Azure SQL DB (11.0.9228.34) with a preview version of the new V12 engine available. Be aware that not all features from on-prem SQL Server are currently supported by Azure SQL DB.